# Did not find fingerprint sensor :( Arduino Mega 2560 Adafruit Fingerprint Sensor

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial, adafruit, heat

I'm getting the following error when I try to enroll fingerprints using the Arduino Mega 2560 microcontroller along with a Fingerprint Scanner:

> Did not find fingerprint sensor :(

The exact devices I'm using are as shown in the links below:

https://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_70487.html?lkid=11637831
https://www.gearbest.com/boards-shields/pp_009769796663.html?wid=1433363

My circuit connection is:

- (Green) TX    =>  Pin 0 [PWM]
- (White) RX    =>  Pin 1 [PWM]

//It doesn't respond when connected to 5V, it only heats up

- (Red) VCC     =>  3.3v
- (Black) GND   =>  GND

The connection is illustrated below:

[image]

The code is shown below:

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>

// On Leonardo/Micro or others with hardware serial, use those! #0 is green wire, #1 is white
// uncomment this line:
 #define mySerial Serial1

// For UNO and others without hardware serial, we must use software serial...
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)
// comment these two lines if using hardware serial
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

uint8_t id;

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit Fingerprint sensor enrollment");

  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);

  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }
}

uint8_t readnumber(void) {
  uint8_t num = 0;

  while (num == 0) {
    while (! Serial.available());
    num = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  return num;
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
  Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");
  id = readnumber();
  if (id == 0) {// ID #0 not allowed, try again!
     return;
  }
  Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
  Serial.println(id);

  while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.print(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);

  p = finger.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Stored!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
}
```

I used the Adafruit Fingerprint library found here:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library

I also soldered the wires from the sensor onto Male Pin Headers for greater connection stability.

All I get is the fingerprint sensor blinking continuously which makes me think it's not faulty but when I try to run the enroll code I get the error message highlighted above.

I also tried connecting using the Software Serial approach like below but that wasn't the solution either:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
```

What could be the problem? Is my connection and code okay? Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

The heat occurs on the encircled area below:
[image]

Comment: Before anything, watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxjLx5RdaSQ&t=183s . I  would say it's damaged goods if it heats up when connected to 5v. That sensor board is supposed to be able to run off that voltage, per the specs listed and educ8ts great video. It's also from gearbest, and gearbest does not have the best track record. Can you pinpoint where the heat is coming from? You may be able to swap a damaged component (if you're lucky).

Comment: It just so happens I had watched it :-) Thanks. I have edited my question to show where the overheating is occurring. Do you know which part is causing this from the snapshot? Or am I overreacting, maybe these heat levels are normal?!

Comment: Could it be the male jumper wires that connect the breadboard to the micro-controller? Because those dance around a bit as you handle the device. There should be a way to secure those, no?

Comment: Mega has 4 hardware Serials. why do you use the first which is used by USB or why SoftwareSerial? and why a breadboard in the middle?

Comment: @Juraj Now that I've established my sensor is in working order and have used it with both SFG Demo and Arduino IDE, I'll try out the hardware serials some more. I had tried them unsuccessfully before if you check out my question above where I used PINs 0 and 1 which work with SFG Demo but not Arduino IDE. I suspect the issue might be with the Adafruit Library since when you attempt to upload the edited code to work with the Hardware Serials, the upload is unsuccessful, unless I'm using the wrong PINs altogether. Suggestions? Either way I'll post my findings here in a couple of days.

Comment: Serial on pins 0, 1 is used by USB. use Serial1 on pin 18 and 19

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out first. I've confirmed that's the case here: `https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/` There's a lot to these tiny computers.

Comment: @Juraj Tested and working. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for your input! Regarding my use of the breadboard, I soldered my fingerprint scanner wiring onto 4 joined male pin-headers so that's why I need the breadboard for now albeit as a temporary solution as I prototype my design.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses @HavocRC and @Juraj

I've successfully come to the following working parameters that I have tested and have given positive results:

> **When using Arduino Mega 2560 with the SFG Demo, we use:**
>
> (Green) TX    =>  Pin 1
>
> (White) RX    =>  Pin 0
>
> (Red) VCC     =>  5V
>
> (Black) GND   =>  GND
>
> **When using Arduino Mega 2560 with the Adafruit Library, we use:**
>
> **Using Hardware Serial Port (Serial1) [Recommended]**
>
> (Green) TX    =>  Pin 19
>
> (White) RX    =>  Pin 18
>
> (Red) VCC     =>  5V
>
> (Black) GND   =>  GND
>
> //Note that you'll comment out the Software Serial initialization
>
> //as directed by the code in the Adafruit Library
>
> ```
> #define mySerial Serial1
> ```
>
> **When using Arduino Mega 2560 with the Adafruit Library, we use:**
>
> **Using Software Serial**
>
> (Green) TX    =>  Pin 10
>
> (White) RX    =>  Pin 11
>
> (Red) VCC     =>  5V
>
> (Black) GND   =>  GND
>
> //The order of the PINs in the code is
>
> ```
> SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
> ```

In the process of testing I also used an older version of Arduino IDE, version 1.0.5 which may have helped to get the sensor working (just a hunch). It turns out the sensor only works with 5V although it heats up a bit (not to fiery levels at a go but I wouldn't leave it turned on if I was away from my laptop for a while).

By the way, for the SFG Demo to work, upload the 'blank' example first, close Arduino and then run SFG Demo. If it works then your fingerprint scanner is in working order.

For the hardware Serial options you can also use alternative PINs as follows:

> **Serial2 on pins 17 (RX) and 16 (TX)**
>
> **Serial3 on pins 15 (RX) and 14(TX)**

Links

http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/SFGDemoV2.0.rar

https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/OldSoftwareReleases

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/